# Python JPype importin Java class get JVM mismatch

Tags: python, java, jpype

I am trying to load JAR file to my python program and use the jar classes and functions.
I'm using:

- Java 1.8.0_311 32bit
- Python 3.8.10 64bit

my code looks like:

```
import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *
classPath = "-Djava.class.path='assets/JAR.jar'"
javaClass = jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), classPath)
```

i got an exception:

```
jpype._jvmfinder.JVMNotSupportedException: JVM mismatch, python is 64 bit and JVM is 32 bit.
```

well its pretty obvious that the exception is the difference between python's and java's enviroments.

Does it have a workaround?

Comment: Instead of JPype use GraalVm :- https://www.graalvm.org/python/

Comment: do you have tutorial or example how to write the same logic using GraalVm

Comment: See https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/python/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Install and use Python 3.8.10 32bit (together with Java 1.8.0_311 32bit) instead of Python 3.8.10 64bit
- Install and use Java 1.8.0_311 64bit (together with Python 3.8.10 64bit) instead of Java 1.8.0_311 32bit

Comment: and what will happen after i compile to EXE file using pyinstaller?

Comment: @pikcahu420 pyinstaller uses the installed python version to create the exe. If you use a 64 bit python version you will still need a matching 64 bit java version (or the other way round: if you want to use a 32 bit java version you need a matching 32 bit python version).